# uwsgi + nginx vs apache + mod-wsgi differences at long-pooling implementation

Tags: django, nginx, mod-wsgi, uwsgi

I've implemented a django application that among other things also implements a long-pooling request for retrieving new system events to the client. To be more specific: the request waits (in django code) up to 30 seconds for new events before returning a response back to the client.

This system worked perfectly under apache + mod-wsgi without any special settings. mod-wsgi was set to 2 processes and 12 threads and this worked just fine.

However, changing the server to nginx + uwsgi introduced a problem for me: I start getting 502 errors when I have more than processes * threads requests pending to the server. As you can imagine, this started happening immediately after deploy as I set uwsgi to only spawn core_count processes.

I'd attach the configs, but don't believe they would help: I just followed the tutorials. There's no special stuff in there. And I imagine uwsgi has a mechanism for handling this properly.

Is there any prescribed way of doing long-pooling on uwsgi?